# How to access super attribute at class level attribute's definition

Tags: python, inheritance

In Python, when defining a class it's possible to use previously defined attributes in new attributes definition without any further reference.

```
class Parent(object):
    a_value = 'a'
    another_value = 'b'
    all_values = (a_value, another_value)
```

Is it possible to do the same in a derived class but still accessing some of these parent attributes?

I tried doing something like this:

```
class Child(Parent):
    a_child_value = 'c'
    all_values = (a_value, another_value, a_child_value)
```

But it seems that it doesn't take into account the Parent inheritance and gives me the following error:

```
NameError: name 'a_value' is not defined
```

So, is there any way to indicate that the `a_value` and `another_value` should be from the parent class instead of the current context?

In my case in particular the values are not strings but rather pre-compiled regular expressions, so I would like to avoid having to create them inside the `__init__` method every time a new instance is created.

Comment: @Moses Koledoye: I wouldn't consider this a duplicate: While the question you indicated implicitly contains the information I was looking for, what is being asked is different. I asked about "how" to do something because I couldn't find it anywhere, and that question asks about "why" it has to be done in this way.

Comment: The dupe target more than answers your question. It describes in more detail what you want; why and how. The questions don't have to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `Parent.a_value` in order to get the value you are after. a_child is a static attribute and therefore attached to the class itself and not a local variable.

```
class Child(Parent):
    a_child_value = 'c'
    all_values = (Parent.a_value, Parent.another_value, a_child_value)
```

If it is derived from something, you  HAVE to type what it is derived from.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a valid solution, since `Child` has not been yet completely defined and it doesn't exist as a valid reference. You can try yourself (which, btw, you should always do before responding any question) and see that it raises the following: `NameError: name 'Child' is not defined`

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I'm very much used to abstracts not statics and that would have worked like that. I did actually test, but I only quickly put together a thing with X as the parent and Y as the child and only checked if I could get "a" attribute (that X had) from the IDE ">>>" thing (don't know the proper name for that line).

Answer (score 1):

like this.

```
class Child(Parent):

    a_child_value = 'c'

    all_values = (Parent.a_value, Parent.another_value, a_child_value)
```

Comment: Yes, that's more like it.

Comment: if you create Parent from object type class. there is a another way to handle it. and that's will make more sense.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "create Parent from object"? Also, if it makes more sense, why don't you use that in the answer instead of what doesn't?

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake. super is suitable for call parent's method.

Comment: It's alright. So, if this is the most valid solution remove the "not the best answer" and I'll accept it as such.

Comment: How would I do case of multiple inheritance. Say `class Child(Parent1, Parent2):`. I want the attribute being accessed according MRO and I do not know which parent possess or overrides it.