# Create class attribute derived from base class's class attribute

Tags: python

I have a base class with a class attribute in Python:

```
class BaseClass():
    TENANT_VARIABLES = # Some kind of dictionary
```

then I have some classes that inherit from that class:

```
class A(BaseClass):
    pass
```

and finally I have the lower-level class in the inheritance, where I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
class LowLevelClass(A):
    VARIABLES = TENANT_VARIABLES.get("BACKEVENTS")
```

How can I refer to the base class's attribute `TENANT_VARIABLES` (which should also be a class attribute of `LowLevelClass`)?

I've tried several approaches like:

```
class LowLevelClass(A):
    VARIABLES = LowLevelClass.TENANT_VARIABLES.get("BACKEVENTS")
```

```
class LowLevelClass(A):
    VARIABLES = cls.TENANT_VARIABLES.get("BACKEVENTS")
```

```
class LowLevelClass(A):
    VARIABLES = super.TENANT_VARIABLES.get("BACKEVENTS")
```

but I have not found the way to be able to access the original value. Only the following approach works, but I don't like it because it is not clear at first sight for a new developer that `LowLevelClass` inherits from `BaseClass`:

```
class LowLevelClass(A):
    VARIABLES = BaseClass.TENANT_VARIABLES.get("BACKEVENTS")
```

Is there an easier way to define attributes in low-level classes based on the base class' classes attributes? Maybe is there some kind of class property? I could do the following but all instances of that class will have the same value, I don't think it makes complete sense that I need to assign it to `self`:

```
class LowLevelClass(A):
    @property
    def VARIABLES(self):
        return self.TENANT_VARIABLES.get("BACKEVENTS")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: how to access super attribute at class level attributes definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39766039/python-how-to-access-super-attribute-at-class-level-attributes-definition)

Comment: Use `A.TENANT_VARIABLES`…?! Since `LowLevelClass` directly inherits from `A`, it's pretty clear why you'd be accessing `A` there.

Comment: Thank you @deceze! your approach seems excellent. Even though it is not directly defined in `A`, this makes everything more clear. I have posted your approach in a Wiki Answer along with another approach I've used too

Comment: You can always use `LowLevelClass.TENANT_VARIBLES.get("BACKEVENT")` directly; there's no specific need to define a new class attribute.

Comment: This is basic inheritance; it applies to *all* class attributes, not just the function-valued ones that define methods. (Low-level developers need to know this, so there's no point sugar-coating it for them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be two approaches:

- @deceze: Use `A.TENANT_VARIABLES`. Since `LowLevelClass` directly inherits from `A`, it's pretty clear why you'd be accessing `A`
- @rodvictor: An alternative approach that also works and makes it transparent:

```
class BaseClass():
   TENANT_VARIABLES = {"BACKEVENTS": "TEST"}
   TYPE = "Unknown"

   @property
   def VARIABLES(self):
       return self.TENANT_VARIABLES.get(self.TYPE)


class A(BaseClass):
   pass


class LowLevelClass(A):
   TYPE = "BACKEVENTS"
```

We can access the Variables for a particular instance with `LowLevelClass().VARIABLES)`